# Kiwi IRC package client with PhoneGap

Tags: node.js, cordova, irc

I am making a PhoneGap app that includes IRC.  I have customized KiwiIRC's interface to match the rest of my app.

I would like to package KiwiIRC's client in the app and have it connect to the remote server.  Is this possible, and how?  I'm pretty new to node.js and it seems nobody else has tried this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kiwi IRC developer here.

The easiest way right now is to simply load your Kiwi IRC instance into an iframe on your app. You can be modifying the client on your server as much as you like without having to update your app each time this way.

The next release of Kiwi IRC will make embedding into apps and websites possible for tighter integration though so you might want to keep an eye out on the mailing list. https://groups.google.com/d/forum/kiwiirc